# Composer doesn't install sub dependencies

Tags: php, composer-php, dependency-management

I have a root package that depends on the package `supertrall/woo-client dev-master as v1.1.6`

`supertrall/woo-client` package depends on the `supertrall/product dev-master as v1.0.0` package

The problem is when I try to install `supertrall/woo-client` in the root package, it says

> supertrall/woo-client dev-master requires supertrall/order dev-master as v1.2.0 -> no matching package found.

However, if I manually install `supertrall/product` to the root package and then install `supertrall/woo-client`, it goes alright. So why composer doesn't install the sub dependencies automatically? I guess it when I do `require supertrall/woo-client` it must automatically install all the packages on which `supertrall/woo-client` depends and so forth. This is so annoying, please help

Comment: Okay, I've figured out that if the packages on which the root package depends require some other packages as "dev-master as version" this error happens. Does anyone know why and how to fix it? I don't want to assign a tag to my sub packages with every commit.

Comment: Don't use tags/versions. Just use branches everywhere. You don't need `as v1.2.0`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that adding

```
{
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true
}
```

to your composer.json should do it for you. Read more about it in [composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability).